# Not able to get sum of array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I wrote the below code to read a file contains an array of numbers and then add them and display the result. However, I am getting the error message which is provided in the link. What is the reason?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Schema;


class ReadFromFile
{
   public static void Main()

{

    StreamReader rea=new StreamReader(@"c:\users\user\desktop\try.txt");
    var lineCount =File.ReadLines(@"c:\users\user\desktop\try.txt").Count();
    int count=(int) lineCount;
    List<int> ad = new List<int>();

   for (int ind = 0; ind < count; ind++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(rea.ReadLine());

        ad.Add(Int32.Parse(rea.ReadLine()));

    }

     int[] num = ad.ToArray();

     int summ=num.Sum();

    rea.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(summ);

    Console.ReadKey();

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you're passing in `null` someplace where you shouldn't be.  Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: You `rea.ReadLine()` twice per loop iteration. P.S. `File.ReadLines(@"c:\users\user\desktop\try.txt").Sum(int.Parse)`

Comment: I am trying to read a text file and contains array of these numbers: ١ ٣ ٣ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٩ ٦ . These are hindi numbers, not Arabic.

Comment: Try : ad.Add(Int32.Parse(rea.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("HIN")));

Comment: Please post the error message and stack trace as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is from these lines:

```
Console.WriteLine(rea.ReadLine());
ad.Add(Int32.Parse(rea.ReadLine()));
```

What's happening is you are getting the count of the number of lines in the file. Say your file has 10 lines. When the loop reaches the last line and you call `ReadLine` method in `Console.WriteLine(rea.ReadLine());`, it returns the last line. But then you call `Readline` method again in `ad.Add(Int32.Parse(rea.ReadLine()));` and the it returns null because the end of file (EOF) has been reached and `Int32.Parse` throws exception because it cannot convert a null into a number.

This is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about `ReadLine` method:

> The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

So not only are you getting the exception, but your sum will be off too because your `ad` list will contain only half the numbers in your file. So if your file has 10 lines, it will only have 5 numbers.

**Fix**

If your file has numbers and you are sure they are numbers, you can use `Int32.Parse`. If you are unsure, then use `Int32.TryParse` which will try and if it fails it will return false. If all you need is the sum and nothing else, you can do it in one line of code like this:

```
File.ReadLines("PathOfYourFile").Sum(line => int.Parse(line));
```

If you are unsure and the file may contain non numeric data, then do it like this:

```
File.ReadLines("PathOfYourFile").Sum(line => 
    {
        int possibleNumber;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out possibleNumber)
        {
            // success so return the number
            return possibleNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            // Maybe log the line number or throw the exception to 
            // stop processing the file or 
            // return a zero and continue processing the file
            return 0; 
        }
    }
```

Finally if you want to do it your way, remove this line and if your file only has numbers, then all should be fine:

```
// remove this so you do not read the line
Console.WriteLine(rea.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Many thanks CodingYoshi, Extremely helpful and it works now

Answer (score 0):

1) You get this error because you use Parse method. When the compiler can't cast input into Int32, Parse method throws an exception.

Use TryParse which returns true if casting is OK else it returns false:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\try.txt");

int number;
int sum = lines.Sum(line => Int32.TryParse(line, out number) ? number : 0);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

2) The logic is wrong as you invoke ReadLine two times in one step of your loop. As a result you add into array only even rows.

Comment: `Sum()` takes a lambada, so you shouldn't need to do `.Select()` on it first. Also, see @CodingYoshi's answer. It clearly sums up the issue, offers several alternatives, and nails the head on the exact reason why it's failing (Reading the last line passes null on the next line).